# Proof that an operator is self-adjoint if and only if its matrix is self-adjoint

Tags: inner-products, self-adjoint-operators, hermitian-matrices

As stated in the [wikipedia page on self-adjoint operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator), $A$ is a self-adjoint operator on an finite-dimensional inner product space $V$ if and only if, given an orthonormal basis, the matrix of $A$ is self-adjoint i.e. equal to its conjugate transpose.

How may this be proven?

Comment: Do you know how to prove that if $T$ is an operator and $B$ is an orthonormal basis then $[T^*]_B=[T]^*_B$? This is a direct consequence.

Comment: ^ and be careful to note that orthonormality is required for the basis; mere orthogonality doesn’t.